# JavaScript event object unseen errors

Tags: javascript, html

I working on trying to understand JavaScript's event object by using the code pasted below.

This code is copied from the YouTube video *[JavaScript event object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9Ad3420Kmw)*. I just can't get it to working. It is supposed output event information in a div below the button. It won't and I can't tell what's going wrong with the code. How can I fix this problem?

```
function getEventDetails(event) {
    var eventDetails =
        "Event Name = " + event.type + "<br/> X = " event.clientX +
        "<br/> Y = " event.clientY + "<br/> Target type = " + event.target.type +
        "<br/> Target tagName " + event.target.tagName;

    document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = eventDetails;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Events</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="getEventDetails(event)">
        <br /><br />
        <div id="resultDiv"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="e.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the javascript code you have there (`function getEventDetails(event) {...}`) actually in the file e.js, or is it just at the top of the same file your HTML is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor problems in your code:

1. `<Input>` tag is not closed.
2. You did not concatenate the string with the value of event here 
   `"<br /> Y = " event.clientY` to `"<br /> Y = " + event.clientY` and
   `"<br /> X = " event.clientX` to `"<br /> X = " + event.clientX`

   ```
       <body>
           <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="getEventDetails(event)" />
           <br /><br />
           <div id="resultDiv"></div>


           <script>
           function getEventDetails(event) {
       var eventDetails = "Event Name = " + event.type + "<br /> X = " +event.clientX 
                                               + "<br /> Y = "+ event.clientY + "<br /> Target type = " + event.target.type
                                               + "<br /> Target tagName " + event.target.tagName;

       document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = eventDetails;
   }
   </script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following a tutorial and want to learn JavaScript event objects, try to understand before HTML DOM events:

> HTML DOM events allow JavaScript to register different event handlers on elements in an HTML document.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Now about your code don't take care about the part "how to show in HTML", but how to get the object event and for this you can just use a "console.log".

```
console.log(event.type);
```

Now, if you like, you can show the events object in HTML:

```
var eventDetails = "";

eventDetails += event.type;
eventDetails += event.clientX;
```

And so on...

And show in HTML:

```
document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = eventDetails;
```

I made snippet code:

```js
function getEventDetails(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    console.log(event.clientX);
    console.log(event.clientY);
    console.log(event.target.type);
    console.log(event.target.tagName);

    var eventDetails = "";

    eventDetails += "Event Name = " + event.type + "<br />";
    eventDetails += "X = " + event.clientX + "<br />";
    eventDetails += "Y = " + event.clientY + "<br />";
    eventDetails += "Target type = " + event.target.type + "<br />";
    eventDetails += "Target tagName = " + event.target.tagName + "<br />";

    document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = eventDetails;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Events</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="getEventDetails(event)">
        <br /><br />
        <div id="resultDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```